# How can a template generate a template in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a "control-group" (Twitter Bootstrap) directive (similar to this http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/13/twitter-bootstrap-control-group-directive-for-angularjs.html but with error handling).

I imagine the directive would output a template that looks like this.

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: errors.name}">
  <label class="control-label" for="{{for}}" {{label}} />
  ...
  <span class="help-inline" ng-repeat="error in errors.name"> {{label}} {{error}} </span>
</div>
```

But the problem is `errors.name` needs to be dynamically generated.

So the directive will be used like this:

```
<control-group label="Name" for="group_name" key="name">
  <input .../>
</control-group>
```

The `key="name"` will be used to generate `{error: errors.{{key}}}` and `ng-repeat="error in errors.{{key}}" {{label}} {error}}`

So it seems like I need a template that can dynamically generate a template.  Is there a way to escape the braces so that it doesn't get interpolated the first time but it will the second time around?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?